# Perl: SMTP failed to connect to mail server

Tags: windows, perl, email, smtp

I have coded a simple Perl script to send mail using MIME::Lite and Net::SMTP modules. But it resulted in the error, **"SMTP Failed to connect to mail server: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately"**.

**Perl script I have tried,**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MIME::Lite;
use Net::SMTP;

my $from = 'agnesgrusteven@gmail.com';
my $to = 'agnesgrusteven@gmail.com';
my $host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

my $subject = 'A test  message by script ';
my $body = "Please ignore this message as this is test from Perl scripts ";

my $msg = MIME::Lite->new (
  From => $from,
  To => $to,
  Subject => $subject,
  Type =>'multipart/mixed'
) or die "Error creating multipart container: $!\n";

$msg->attach (
  Type => 'TEXT',
  Data => $body
) or die "Error adding the text message part: $!\n";

MIME::Lite->send('smtp', $host, Timeout=>60);
$msg->send;
```

**Actual error I got,**

```
G:\>perl SampleEmail.pl
SMTP Failed to connect to mail server: A non-blocking socket operation could not
 be completed immediately.
 at SampleEmail.pl line 26.
```

Please help me what specifically I need to check to send mail properly.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you state exact version of  perl you use? I have found references to such problems regarding specific compiler used to compile perl https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bceb27d0-621b-41ee-b536-df8c38f71598/vs-2010-winsock-problem?forum=wsk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for answering my Own question, but this may help to someone.

After a month of search finally I found why my socket is failing to connect to SMTP with proper host and pass code. In my thing the IO::Socket module get collapsed. I have **replaced IO::Socket** with the fresh one and the whole thing worked. I guess, the reason for the module collapse is may be the way I manually download the required modules from different site and place it in the Perl lib and not from Perl Package Manager.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## MIME::Lite / Net::SMTP v3.* - sending via smtp.gmail.com

**Q1**: Can you telnet smtp (25) port at `smtp.gmail.com`?  Do you get SMTP greeting message?

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
```

**A1**: NO => It is quite likely that your outgoing connections to smtp port are blocked to avoid *outgoing* spam.

**Q2**: Can you telnet msa (587) port at `smtp.gmail.com`?  Do you get SMTP greeting message?

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

**A1**: YES => send via msa (587) or smtps (465).  `MIME::Lite` can connect to smtps (465) port using `Net::SMTP` version 3.*.
[ **WARNING:** see [MIME::Lite 3.030 - NET::SMTP with smtps (port 465)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45588971/mimelite-3-030-netsmtp-with-smtps-port-465) ]

```
# use smtps (465) port - it requires Net::SMTP version 3.*
# use debugging (Debug=>1) for initial tests
MIME::Lite->send('smtp', $host, SSL => 1, Timeout => 60,
  AuthUser => $user, AuthPass => $pass, 
  Debug => 1);
```

Comment: Hi @Andrzej, Thanks for Reply, I am using Net Smtp of version 3.05 and MIME lite of version 3.01. I have tested with the port 465 as you stated. I am resulting in the same error again. I can able to ping the host too. Then why it is telling failed to connect to mail server. Do I need to check anything else.

Comment: [Q2] Do you get SMTP greeting message when you telnet port 587 at smtp.gmail.com? (Is it perl's fault?)

Comment: I checked with the command - `open smtp.gmail.com 587`, i got reply as - `220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP 188sm1896254qhi.1 - gsmtp` .. I also tried with the host - `open secure.emailsrvr.com 587`   , where i got reply as `220 smtp15.relay.iad3a.emailsrvr.com ESMTP - VA Code Section 18.2-152.3:1 forbid
s use of this system for unsolicited bulk electronic mail (Spam)
421 4.4.2 Timeout exceeded


Connection to host lost.

Press any key to continue...`

Comment: How can I find the port number for the host name ?

Comment: You can use `telnet` to test if ports **25** and **58788 are accessible - you should get SMTP greeting message.  With port 465 telnet will establish connection but AFAIK (standard) telnet will not negotiate SSL so it will not get SMTP greeting message - but you can use (standard) telnet for testing port 465 anyway.

Comment: I have checked that too. Finally I found that IO socket modules are corrupted. I have un installed it completely. Then installed as fresh now it is WORKING.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andrzej,

Comment: Now you've fixed the underlying connection problems, can I suggest that you stop using MIME::Lite and Net::SMTP and replace them with something simpler like [Email::Sender](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender) or [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer)?

Answer (score -1):

If you're running this on a well-configured Linux server, you might have better luck if you take out

```
use Net::SMTP
```

and

```
MIME::Lite->send('smtp', $host, Timeout=>60);
```

and just let `MIME::Lite` use its defaults – usually it lets `sendmail` handle the message.

Comment: Hi @Mscha, I have checked as you stated using sendmail, But I am still circling around the same error.