# MIME::Lite 3.030 - NET::SMTP with smtps (port 465)

Tags: perl, smtp

`MIME::Lite` can pass extra parameters to `Net::SMTP` constructor.
Version `MIME::Lite` 3.030 does not include `SSL` on its list of passed `Net::SMTP` parameters.

Is it possible to change it **without** modifying `MIME::Lite` source code?

```
   1 package MIME::Lite;
     ...
 355 $VERSION = '3.030';
     ...
2843 my @_net_smtp_opts = qw( Hello LocalAddr LocalPort Timeout
2844                          Port ExactAddresses Debug );
     ....
2847 sub __opts {
2848     my $args=shift;
2849     return map { exists $args->{$_} ? ( $_ => $args->{$_} ) : () } @_;
2850 }
     ....
2852 sub send_by_smtp {
         ....
2876     my %opts = __opts(\%args, @_net_smtp_opts);
2877     my $smtp = MIME::Lite::SMTP->new( $hostname, %opts )
2878       or Carp::croak "SMTP Failed to connect to mail server: $!\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is wrapping `__opts` with some function that modifies the parameters are passed to it.

In line 2876:

```
my %opts = __opts(\%args, @_net_smtp_opts);
```

The advantage here is that after the reference to `%args`, the rest of parameters is always the array `@net_smtp_opts` defined earlier. Unfortunately you can't modify its value at distance (it's a lexical variable), but you can do something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use MIME::Lite;
use Class::Method::Modifiers;

around 'MIME::Lite::__opts' => sub {
  my $orig = shift;
  push(@_,'SSL') if @_ >= 2 && $_[1] eq 'Hello';
  my (@ret) = $orig->(@_);
  return @ret;
};
```

This way every call to `MIME::Lite::__opts` is "intercepted", and you have the ability to modify the parameters at your will.

Comment: `before` method does not get `$orig` parameter but only original `@_`. I was able to change existing @_ element but `before` ignored attempts to append extra parameter via `push(@_,'SSL')`.

Comment: right.. thanks to the edit (and sorry for not checking thoroughly)

Comment: btw I understand you're trying to infer what specific array has been passed to `__opts` looking at its content. A slightly less error prone version (what if RJBS or someone else changes the array elements order?) could be `push( @_, 'SSL') if grep { /Hello/ } @_`

Comment: After shifting `$orig` `$_[0]` is a reference to hash being inspected/reduced. It is a dirty hack anyway => The Right Way should be to change/patch `MIME::Lite` sources.  I purge `MIME::Lite` from my scripts anyway but it will take a few months as a non critical task. [`man MIME::Lite` : MIME::Lite is not recommended by its current maintainer.]