# Class::Method::Modifiers - How to apend parameters in "before"?

Tags: perl

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45590793/2139766 for the original problem.

How to **append** parameter(s) to `@_` in `before` provided by `Class::Method::Modifiers`?

```
before 'MIME::Lite::__opts' => sub {
  # grep { s/^Hello$/SSL/ } @_; # OK - changes $_[1]   
  push(@_,'SSL'); # no effect
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@_` is scoped to your sub. Changes to it can't be seen on the outside.

You noticed that changing the *elements* of `@_` had an effect on scalars outside of the sub, but that's because the existing *elements* of `@_` are aliased to scalars in the caller. But `@_` itself is a local variable, so adding and removing elements has no effect on the caller.

You can use `around` to pass the original method a different `@_`.

```
around 'MIME::Lite::__opts' => sub {
    my $orig = shift;
    return $orig->(@_, 'SSL');
};
```

---

Note that changing `$method->(@_);` to  `&$method;` in `Class/Method/Modifiers.pm` would allow you to do what you want (by having your sub use the caller's `@_` instead of being giving it its own). However, that would cause a lack of symmetry with `after`, which has no way of manipulating the returned value.

---

> *`grep { s/^Hello$/SSL/ } @_; # OK - changes $_[1]`*

No, that's not ok.

First of all,

```
grep { s/^Hello$/SSL/ } @_;
```

is a poor way to write

```
map { s/^Hello$/SSL/ } @_;
```

which is a poor way to write

```
s/^Hello$/SSL/ for @_;
```

That said, you shouldn't do any of those. They alter the arguments in the "real" caller, so you are risking nasty side-effects.

Even claiming it works if pushing it, seeing as the following will crash!

```
before method => sub {
    s/^Hello$/SSL/ for @_;
};

$o->method("Hello");  # Dies: Can't modify constant item in substitution
```